# C++ accept() of winsock2.h keeps giving 10038 error

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, winsock

I am facing an issue with the accept() function in the below code. It keeps giving me **10038 error**. I read about the error 10038 (WSAENOTSOCK). But I can't find the exact issue here. Similar Linux code works fine as the server code.

PS: I am running this in Visual Studio on Windows.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("ClientServerThread.log", "a+");
    SOCKET serverSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int nCode;
    if ((nCode = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s: %d\n", "WSAStartup() failed with code", nCode);
        fclose(fp);
        return false;
    }
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s: %ld\n", "socket() failed with error", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        fclose(fp);
        exit(1);
    }
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(8000);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int bindRes = bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if (bindRes == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s: %ld\n", "bind() failed with error", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        fclose(fp);
        exit(1);
    }

    int listenRes = listen(serverSocket, 10);
    if (listenRes == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s: %ld\n", "listen() failed with error", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        fclose(fp);
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%s...\n", "Server listening for client");

    while (1)
    {
        int clientSock = accept(listenRes, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, (int*)sizeof(serverAddr));
        if (clientSock == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            //10038
            fprintf(fp, "%s: %ld\n", "accept() failed with error", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            fclose(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
        fprintf(fp, "%s: %d\n", "Client Found", clientSock);
        closesocket(clientSock);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error code `WSAENOTSOCK` seems fairly self-explanatory.  You have...

```
int listenRes = listen(serverSocket, 10);
```

followed by...

```
int clientSock = accept(listenRes, ...
```

So you're passing the value returned by `listen` as the socket parameter to `accept`.  Your `accept` call should be (untested)...

```
int clientSock = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, (int*)sizeof(serverAddr));
```